# Emgu CV 3.2 new method declare

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, emgucv

I'm using Emgu cv 3.2 with C#

The problem is many methods have been updated and it takes so much time to figure out alike `Capture ()` change to `Video Capture ()`.

Can someone provide a list of method that has been altered or updated in this latest version?

Here, I'm posting two code that works fine by using emgu cv 2.4.10, but got several error while using 3.2. All you need to change is the method name. I got 21 error.

Error are:

> type or namespace 'Contour<>' could not be found the name
>   'ADAPTIVE_THRESHOLD_TYPE' does not exist THRESH does not exist
>   CvInvoke does not contain a definition for 'cvShowImage' Image  does not...
>   CvInvoke does not contain a definition for 'cvWaitKey' CvInvoke does
>   not contain a definition for 'cvConvert' CvInvoke does not contain a
>   definition for 'cvDrawContours'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here im posting the link of those two code which were written by uing Emgu cv 2.4

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_KNN_Character_Recognition_Machine_Learning_Visual_Basic_C_Sharp/blob/master/GenerateData.cs

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_KNN_Character_Recognition_Machine_Learning_Visual_Basic_C_Sharp/blob/master/TrainAndTest.cs

what methods should i need to alter for using that code in Emgu cv 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Fahad,
AFAIK there is no guide to what changes have been made to classes between version 2.4.10 and 3.2. Porting code between versions of a free SDK can be difficult. Even paid SDKs do not always maintain naming conventions.

Wish there was a better answer.

Doug

Comment: I got it, i have to research own my own to sort out, 
well if anyone could solve this : 


 bool ContourIsValid(Contour<Point> contour)
        {
            if (contour.Area >= MIN_CONTOUR_AREA)
            {         // obviously in a production grade program
                return true;                                // we would have a much more robust function for
            }                                               // identifying if a contour is valid !!
            return false;
        }

i got an error " namespace name 'Contour' could not be found